Using implementationFactory with related services in Dependency Injection
I read the documentation about Dependency Injection but I cannot find the correct approach to using implementationFactory when the delegate must resolve related services from the DI-container to configure another service. (all services implement IDisposable)
IHost hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(
        (context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IExampleTransientService, ExampleTransientService>();
            services.AddScoped<IExampleScopedService, ExampleScopedService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IExampleSingletonService, ExampleSingletonService>();
        })
    .ConfigureServices(
        (context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IServiceLifetimeReporter, ServiceLifetimeReporter>(
                sp =>
                {
                    var transient = sp.GetRequiredService<IExampleTransientService>();
                    var scoped = sp.GetRequiredService<IExampleScopedService>();
                    var singleton = sp.GetRequiredService<IExampleSingletonService>();

                    return new ServiceLifetimeReporter(transient, scoped, singleton);
                });
        })
    .Build();

(I understand that example will work also without implementationFactory)
I cannot understand how to correctly write implementationFactory in the second ConfigureServices method.

Will DI create a local scope for implementationFactory?
Should I manually create local scope in implementationFactory (using CreateScope)?
Does DI takes responsibility for disposing (Dispose()) objects before it was built?
What will the correct approach be in this (and similar) situation?

I experimented with different approaches:

Use the example above (Dispose() wasn't invoked)
Create local scope (Dispose() invoked for Transient and Scoped lifetimes)
Use using to invoke Dispose() methods (Dispose() invoked for all lifetimes)


Why are you using the factory opposed to simply calling services.AddTransient<IServiceLifetimeReporter, ServiceLifetimeReporter>();?

Yes, I can use this syntax in the current situation. It is just a simple example and I am interested in situations when DI cannot configure itself and I must use implementationFactore with mainly resolving services.
